# Evaluating a series with a constant as a bound

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation

I'm trying to find an expression to evaluate a series given a bound that is some unknown constant.

For example, the simple summation below can be expressed as such:

$\sum \limits_{x=1}^{n}x=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$

However, I'm struggling on how to start to find a similar expression for this particular summation in which the constant bound is found within the summation itself:

$\sum \limits_{N=1}^{A-1}\normalsize\frac{A-N}{A(\frac{N}{A}-1)^2}$

Comment: Your sum involves dividing by $0$ for $N=A$. Did you mean to sum up to $A-1$?

Comment: Yes! Thanks for catching that, I'll make the edit...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Assuming your bounds are $\sum_{N=1}^{A-1}$, otherwise you divide by 0.*

Rewrite
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{N=1}^{A-1}\frac{A-N}{A(\frac{N}{A}-1)^2}
&= A\sum_{N=1}^{A-1}\frac{A-N}{A^2(\frac{N}{A}-1)^2}
= A\sum_{N=1}^{A-1}\frac{A-N}{(N-A)^2}
= A\sum_{N=1}^{A-1}\frac{1}{A-N}
= A\sum_{n=1}^{A-1}\frac{1}{n}\\
&= A H_{A-1}
\end{align}$$
where $H_n$ is the partial sum (up to $n$) of the [Harmonic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)). (In particular, when $A\to\infty$ your sum will be asymptotically equivalent to $A\ln A$.)

Comment: Very cool. How did go about simplifying (A-N) to simply n?

Comment: @somil  Try the change of indice $n=A-N$. Then the sum of $\frac{1}{A-N}$ for $N$ ranging from $1$ to $A-1$  becomes the sum of $\frac{1}{n}$, for $n$ ranging from $A-1$ to $1$.

Comment: Oh, I see. Also, is there any way to express the partial sum of a harmonic series as an   expression?

Comment: Not really, no. "It is what it is" (although we have very good understanding of what $H_n$ behaves like asymptotically, when $n\to\infty$). You may want to check [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number).

Comment: I was afraid so. Finally, what was your thought process when going about simplifying this summation. Did you have an intuition that this summation may be proportional to the harmonic series?

Comment: @somil Not at first: but seeing the $(N/A-1)^2$ in the denominator, trying to multiply this by $A^2$ to get $(N-A)^2$ and see what simplifies seemed like a natural step.

Comment: I see, that's pretty reasonable. It may be better if I added some context to how I came about this summation. Basically the problem I'm considering is: If you have an array of size A and you keep randomly selecting indices of that array, what is the expected (average) value of random indices that you must choose before you have selected every index (given that the same index may be selected more than once). I believe this summation gives that value.

Comment: Sounds like a [coupon collector's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem#Answer)... so you're right indeed.

Comment: Wow, simply amazing... I would likely have not discovered that otherwise